# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'index') (https://mantine.dev/)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rte, mantine

I'm using [Rich Text Editor](https://mantine.dev/others/rte/) of [Mantine](https://mantine.dev/) in a next js project.
It's working fine for all the control except for List (both ordered & unordered).
When using list in this rte, it gives the following error 
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'index')`

I'm using the code given in official documentation [here](https://mantine.dev/others/rte/#usage).

I've gone through the issues on [Mantine github](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues) but none of that seem to fix this issue.
Can anyone please tell me how to fix this, or suggest any other **rich text editor** for react / next.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you get the following error in your code? Or in the library code?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski in the library code. As far as I can understand there is some issue in quill js code, the underneath library that mantine rte uses.

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example with how you use the component?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski https://pastebin.com/M9TZUmY2 this is the code causing error

Comment: I don't see `defaultValue` anywhere in the documentation

Comment: @KonradLinkowski initially I was using `value` which is there in docs, it was also causing the same error. Later I changed it to `defaultValue` which was suggested by a mantine contributor in one of the related issues.

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this issue is caused by react strict mode, try disabling it

Answer (score 0):

Disabling react strict mode does cause the error go away. However, `unorderedlist` or `orderedlist` does not work as expected. No bullet points or numbers are shown before the indented line. But, yes, the lines are indented.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33340541)